# Why iOS app icons is hanging and creating an another install icon during installation on iPhone 6 plus?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

We are installing our app using Diawi.com link.It is installing perfectly on iPhone 5c device as I have test. But it is creating an another install icon on iPhone 6 plus device while our app install completely.

We have try by regenerate app id and provisioning profile But install issue is still coming on iPhone 6 plus device.
Please review the attach screenshot and advice us how to debug this problem.

Comment: It mayn't related with iOS version. Please check app name, bundle identifier which are same as older one. If it's differ, it will install as new app.

Comment: We have try to install a new app after uninstalling the older one, But we have found same issue

Comment: as @Mani says.. your old app and new app version will be different thats why this was happen..

Comment: Have had the very same situation while testing on iPhone 6+. I think, this is some kind of bug in iOS, but only happens on iPhone 6+. I don't think that could be problem to anyone, anyways, after installation is complete, those 2 icons will merge to 1.

Comment: @fahri Thanks for your comment. But in our case installing process is not disappearing while our app installation is complete as you can view in the attach screenshot .
I have also change my bundle identifier and regenerate the app id and provisioning profile. But Issue is still coming .

Comment: It might be due to different app identifiers, the one installing has different identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The icon is only shown at the time of installation, when this installation is completed, this icon is removed.  In iOS 8 if app is already installed this icon is separately shown whereas in earlier version it is replaced with the previous installed one.